# Domain name and Dynamic IP Addresse

Tags: ssl, dns, domain-name, dyndns

I have recently acquired a domain name from GoDaddy. At home i am trying to setup a nextcloud server. Since my ISP serves me a dynamic IP addresse i had to create another domain name on no-ip website. Furthermore, i want to forward http requests to https. The following questions rises:

1. Do i create the ssl certificate (with let’s encrypt) for the godaddy domain or the no-ip domain?
2. What is the correct forwarding sequence here? Assume godaddy is foo.com and no-ip bar.dyndns.me and the user types foo.com, my server apache settings would forward foo.com:80 to :443 but this i guess should be corrected to my dyndns. I am confused.

I would appreciate any help - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you are making it too complicated. Instead of using a redirect you should request a static ip from you isp. this costs money varying by your provider but then you only need one domain. you then apply the ssl certificate to that domain and enforce ssl only with your hosting server (i.e apache, iis).

Comment: Sadly i can not afford the costs of static IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple app/script to manage the Dynamic DNS from your server using the GoDaddy Api, thats what i have been doing for ~3 years now as my ISP want a stupid amount for a static IP. I have mine pinging out every 10 mins to check if my IP changed (ISP sucked for a while and mine would change several times a day)

Here are some links to various implementations of the GoDaddy API

[BASH](https://www.instructables.com/id/Quick-and-Dirty-Dynamic-DNS-Using-GoDaddy/)

[Python](https://github.com/CarlEdman/godaddy-ddns)

[Powershell](https://github.com/chadbirch/GoDaddy-DDNS-Automation/tree/develop/powershell)

Answer (score 0):

So I think I have a fix for this, before I give you my answer I will outline problems with other solutions.

1. Static IP from your ISP. The problem with this is it may cost too much. (However if it’s cheap I’d probably do this solution)
2. Script and update godaddy DNS. This is okay however only if you can allow for some outage time between changes. (The DNS will take time to Propagate up to 24 hours)
3. Upgrade your noip account to a plus managed DNS it costs $29.95 a year. However it will allow you to bring your own domain name from another provider like go daddy. Depending how often your noip client is running there could be a very small outage between changes.

https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/can-i-use-my-own-domain-name-with-no-ip/